# How to update a meta field of type array in Gutenberg

Tags: custom-field, javascript, hooks, block-editor

In a plugin I'm building for Gutenberg, I register a meta field named `_related_posts`, which stores an array of post ids:

**PHP:**

```
function register_meta_fields() {
    register_post_meta( '', '_related_posts', array(
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'single'       => true,
        'type'         => 'array',
        'show_in_rest' => array(
            'schema' => array(
                'type'  => 'array',
                'items' => array(
                    'type' => 'integer',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'auth_callback' => function() {
            return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
        }
    ) );
}
```

I'm using the `useEntityProp` hook to get and set this meta field in JS:

**JS:**

```
const [ meta, setMeta ] = useEntityProp(
    'postType',
    'post',
    'meta'
);
```

I have a `onUpdateRelatedPosts()` function that gets called when the user selects a post from a list:

**JS:**

```
function onUpdateRelatedPosts( post ) {
    setMeta( { ...meta, '_related_posts': [post.id] } );
}
```

This function takes a post object as an argument and stores its id in the `_related_posts` meta field, but I can't get it to work as I want. It doesn't append the id at the end of the array but replaces the whole meta field with the added id.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this: `'_related_posts': [post.id]`, you're actually overriding the entire array or the meta value, so to instead append an item to the existing array, you can use the [spread (`...`) syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like so: `'_related_posts': [ ...meta._related_posts, post.id ]`.

But you may *not* want to update the meta if the selected post ID is already in the current meta value, i.e.

```js
// Add the post (ID) if it's not already in the list.
if ( meta._related_posts.indexOf( post.id ) < 0 ) {
    setMeta( { ...meta, '_related_posts': [ ...meta._related_posts, post.id ] } );
}
```

That's just a suggestion (to avoid *duplicate* values), though.

And BTW, for property names that do not contain characters that are *not* alphanumeric or underscore (`_`), it's not mandatory to enclose the property name in quotes. So for example in your case, `_related_posts:` (as opposed to having the quotes: `'_related_posts':`) would be fine. :)

Comment: Thank you for posting the id duplicate check code in addition to the answer to my question. Very appreciated.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, but anyway, thank you for the edit, @hgodinho :)